# How do I load a GIF-image from computer in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gif, io-monad, gloss

I want to have a GIF-image looping in the background of a game (For example with Gloss Juicy or module Codec.Picture.Gif)

Managed to work with a BMP image like this:

```
image :: IO Picture 
image = loadBMP "image.bmp"
```

But now I want to do the same with a GIF image:

```
loadGifFile :: FilePath -> IO Image 
loadGifFile = "image.gif"
```

Can't get it to work.

Thankful for any tip how to do it.

Comment: [Hoogle says](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=loadBMP): `loadBMP :: FilePath -> IO Picture`.

Comment: Why are you assigning "image.gif" to loadGifFile instead of passing it as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to do some more work. `loadBMP` just loads a BMP file into a bitmap, which is a single image. However an animated GIF is a more complex file format which has several frames in it. GLOSS simply doesn't support that out of the box.

You could use [JuicyPixels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.3/docs/Codec-Picture-Gif.html) to decode a GIF file and then write some code to convert that into a list of GLOSS Bitmaps. Then use `animate` to draw those images in sequence.